# How to pick .dwg extension file in android file picker. When my file manager open that time .dwg file is disable. Not selectable

Tags: android

String[] mimeTypes =
{
"application/acad",
"image/vnd.dwg",
"image/x-dwg"
};

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 9);
```

Comment: From Android's standpoint, those are obscure MIME types -- AutoCAD DWG files are mostly used on desktop operating systems. I would not expect the platform to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent;
                String[] mimeTypes =
                    {
                        "image/*",
                        "application/pdf",
                        "image/x-dwg",
                        "image/x-dxf",
                        "image/x-3ds",
                        "application/zip",
                        "application/octet-stream",
                    };
                intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 9);

After adding "application/octet-stream" .bin type my files are visible
```